# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' with mysql-connector-python already installed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mysql-connector, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to connect my python scripts to an MySQL or MariaDB Server on my RaspberryPi4.

My python script right now just contains `import mysql.connector`. But when I try to start it via `sudo python3 startdb.py` I just get `import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'` as an error.

I get an other error, when I start the script via `sudo python startdb.py`:  `import mysql.connector ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`.

I searched for a solution on many sites or forums. I mostly just found various versions of `pip install mysql-connector-python` (also with `pip3`, `mysql-connector-python-rf` or `mysql-connector`) to run but none of them worked for me. The only difference I recognized is that I previously got the error `ModuleNotFoundError` with both `sudo python` and `sudo python3`, but now I only get it with `sudo python3`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Could the fact that my script isn't in a sub-directory of /home/pi/, but instead of /home/, be the problem?

Edit: I just tried executing the script via the desktop mode using my mouse and just clicking on run and it worked. But when I'm using the command line in desktop mode or with a SSH session it doesn't work.

Another Edit: It looks like when I'm starting the script without sudo it'll work just fine. Don't actually know why's that, but I'm good for now. But would be very interesting to know and understand why the sudo makes it "crash".

Thanks and happy to hear some solutions :D

Cooki

Comment: have you try to install mysql-connector-python-rf with ```pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf```and then import like this ```import mysql.connector```

Answer (score 0):

raspbian give user mode in running, just in Desktop gives some permission to user for run app as root to access all necessary attributes , use `sudo` with all initial steps when you download and install project package's